# Search and keyboard shortcuts with readthedocs theme for MkDocs?

Tags: mkdocs

I've spent the past day messing around with mkdocs and I now have a basic understanding of it. I've really come to like the clone of the readthedocs theme. However, I don't have the ability to use keyboard shortcuts or the search popup modal when this theme is active.

I've tried adding this to the mkdocs.yml file, but it doesn't help:

```
shortcuts:
    help: 191    # ?
    next: 78     # n
    previous: 80 # p
    search: 83   # s
```

I've spent some time on google, but I'm not finding anything useful.